# How to draw from conditional Weibull distribution

Tags: r, survival, weibull-distribution

I would like to draw random numbers in R from a conditional Weibull distribution which is given by `P(x<=t+T| x>T) = 1-(1-F(t+T))/(1-F(T))`, where `F` is the Weibull-CDF and `T` is the time that has elapsed without event. 
I know the function `rweibull` for drawing random numbers, but is there a similar function for the conditional distribution?

Comment: There is the `truncdist` package which implements the inversion method mentioned by @jcken

Comment: @Jarle Tufto, thanks. Will look into this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume $ T, \lambda, \kappa $ are fixed. We can use the Probability Integral Transform (PIT). In essense, the PIT says that the CDF of a random variable follows a $U(0,1)$ distribution, so drawing $U(0,1)$ samples and running them through $F^{-1}(x)$ gives draws of $X$. If we can draw samples of $x$, we can then estimate the $P(x < t + T | X > T)$ via monte carlo. Nb I use the form of the Weibull that is used on wikipedia [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution ].

To apply the inversion method, we want to sample values of $x = t + T$.

We have
\begin{align}
 p = P(x < t+T | X>T) &= 1 - \frac{1 - F(t+T)}{1 - F(T)} \\
& = 1 - \frac{1 - \left( 1 - \exp\left\{ -\lambda^{-\kappa}(t+T)^{\kappa} \right\} \right)}{1 - \left( 1 - \exp\left\{ -\lambda^{-\kappa}(T)^{\kappa} \right\} \right)}\\
& = 1 - \exp \left\{ \lambda^{-\kappa}T^\kappa - \lambda^{-\kappa}(t + T)^\kappa \right\}
\end{align}

Some algebra leads to $t + T = \left\{ T^\kappa - \lambda^\kappa \log(1-p) \right\}^{1/\kappa}$

The following `R` code can then be used to draw samples of $X$.

````
draw.x <- function(n, lambda, kappa, T0){
  p <- runif(n)

  ( T0^kappa - lambda^kappa *log(1-p))^(1/kappa) 

}

## estimate P(X < 5+1 = 6 | X > 5)
n.draws <- 10^4

samples <- draw.x(n.draws, 1.5, 1, 5)

prob.estimate <- sum(samples < 6)/n.draws
prob.estimate
## if kappa = 1=> exponential distribution rate = 1/lambda
## compare to exponential 1/lambda
pexp(6-5, 1/1.5); prob.estimate


hist(samples); abline(v = 6,col = 2, lwd = 2)

```
````

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I was aware of the Inverse Method (what you call PIT), but didn't realize that we can manually derive the inverse in this case. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In Mathematica you can do it easily,

```
 f[a_, b_, T_] = 
  ProbabilityDistribution[
   1 - (1 - CDF[WeibullDistribution[a, b], t + T])/
    CDF[WeibullDistribution[a, b], T], {t, T, \[Infinity]}];
data = RandomVariate[f[3.5, 1, 2], 25]
```

> {2.32932, 2.63388, 2.29273, 3.60003, 3.64601, 3.27736, 2.89225, \
>   2.9748, 3.18756, 2.49238, 2.24663, 3.58997, 3.282, 3.28332, 2.54555, \
>   3.33817, 2.6722, 2.94851, 3.07248, 2.23742, 2.49302, 3.13033, \
>   3.23821, 3.47035, 3.50443}

I am not sure about t and T, you can adjust them yourself.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the answer! I was just looking for an R solution in this case.